# React native Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' after changing the name of app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-api, google-client

I have to change the name of my app I used react-native-rename which worked good but I am getting following error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'
> No matching client found for package name 'com.newName'
```

but if I change the 'com.newName' to 'com.oldName' at every where in my app it starts working however its a separate app which is clone of oldName app.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my google-services.json and I also re-configured my app on Firebase to get new configuration for google-services.json